# How to select from table where query equal to any number

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a table that contains `Names` `About` `Friend` `ID`, and I want to get the following

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Friend` = '$me' AND `ID` = 'Any Number'");
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$Names = $arr["Names"];
echo $Names;
echo "</br>";
}
```

So I want to select where ID equal to any number.

Comment: equal to any? Why not to remove condition then?

Comment: deleting `AND ID = 'any number'`

Comment: do you any number but not null?

Comment: @piddl0r Yes any number but not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the id part from your query or you can write this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Friend` = '$me' AND ID >0");
```

it can also work well in future if you want to add any condition on id you can edit it.

Comment: I don't understand this answer the question is about **any number**. let's say I choose -1 then condition is wrong moreover numbers like 0 also won't fit.

Comment: sometimes the requirement works on code which are absurd for someone but useful for another. Actually there is no need to write the id part but due to some type of may be linked with it may be not working for this guy and adding id part could solve his problem.

Comment: what could make sense is only `ID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: All answers are correct like code without id and id is not null but since these codes didn't work for him, so I suggested to try it. If it works for somebody then its ok . Meaning is all same and I totally understand the 'Id is not null' code is the correct way of writing.

Comment: The question should be changed because maybe this answer helps him which is good but for sure it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `ID` part:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Friend` = '$me'");
```

also, don't use `mysql_*`, they are deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @KevinMartin, what's the error, and did you read the manual? `mysqli` is not a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean Equal to any as you stated then you should remove condition

```
AND `ID` = 'Any Number'
```

Morover I would suggest to use PDO or Mysqli because mysql_* functions are depracated and will be removed in future relases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if ID is numeric you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Friend` = '$me' AND `ID` REGEXP ('[0-9]')
```

Comment: [0-9] is equal for 1 digit not for number number would be `[0-9]+`

Answer (score 1):

Use IS NOT NULL

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Friend` = '$me' AND `ID` IS NOT NULL);
```

It will return any number including 0 but it will not return the ones with empty values.

I hope this helps.